# Zeros of exponential

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm just want to be sure if the function $f(z)=e^{-iz}, z\in \mathbb C$, has no complex or real zeros??

Answer (score 10):

$f(x+iy)=e^{-ix+y}=e^{y}(\cos(x)-i\sin(x))$

In order for $f(z)=0$ you need

$$e^y\cos(x)=0 \,,$$
and
$$e^y\sin(x)=0 \,.$$

You can easily see why that is not possible.

Answer (score 8):

That is correct.

Since both $e^z$ and $e^{-z}$ are entire, they have no poles.  Since they are reciprocals of each other, it follows that they have no zeros.

Hope that helps,

Comment: That's all what I need... thanks all.

Comment: How do you know they are both entire? (I'd think by the time figured that out you'd already know there are no zeroes)

Comment: But "entire" does *not* include that they have no zeros (only that they have no poles)

Comment: This is basically the standard way to see that $e^z$ is never zero, but no reference to analyticity is necessary.  Since $e^z\cdot e^{-z}=e^{z-z}=e^0=1$ for all $z$ (and $e^z$ is a complex number), $e^z$ is never $0$.

Comment: @Gottfried:  Of course being entire does not mean it has no zeros. But these two functions are entire _and_ reciprocals of each other.... so it does.

Comment: @Mitch:  I take $e^z$ to be defined by its power series which converges uniformly on all of $\mathbb{C}$ by the Weierstrass M-test.

Comment: @Eric: well, that's correct. But the consequences of the symmetry and reciprocity are just *the* key idea/argument; so I'd always explicate it: "Since e^z is entire so is e^-z. Then they both have no poles. But because they are also their mutual reciprocals they also cannot have a zero" - or something like that. (Just to focus the attention of the OP at the key idea)

Comment: Smart and concise! +1

Comment: No finite zeros, right? Can it be said the exponential has a single infinite order zero at infinity?

Answer (score 1):

$\exp(z) \cdot \exp(-z) = \exp(z - z) = \exp(0) = 1$, so $\exp(z) = 0 \implies \frac{1}{\exp(-z)} = 0$

Answer (score 0):

$e^{-iz}=e^{-ia+b}=e^{-ia}e^{b}$ so if it equals $0$ then $e^{-ia}$ must be zero, since we know that $e^{b}$ is never zero when $b$ is real (graph it on your calculator if you don't want to prove it!).  So we have that $\frac{1}{e^{ia}}=0$ which is impossible.